# Combining dash python app with php html page

Tags: php, html, python-3.x, plotly-dash

I would like to ask if I can have the option to run an already-implemented python dash app with visualization, checkoboxes etc. to a php- html server.

I know that plotly has the bellow function, but it is only for the graphs.

```
plot(fig,
     include_plotlyjs=False,
     output_type='div')
```

So i was wondering if there is similar function or another way for the whole dash app to convert it to html in order to be used by the php server.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run Dash in an Iframe, which should work for your particular setup.

More details can be found here.

https://dash.plotly.com/integrating-dash